# Android - problems with sprite and thread understanding

Tags: android, multithreading, 2d, sprite

I have thread class:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {


private GameView view;
private boolean running = false;
static final long FPS = 3;

public GameThread(GameView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    running = run;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    long ticksPS = 1000/FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while (running) {

        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {   

            view.addElements("left_top");
            view.addElements("right_top");

            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {

            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }

        sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);


            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    sleep(10);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    }

}
```

This class update my canvas and add elements on left-top side of screen and right-top side of screen. I need to put explosion sprite animation, very fast play them and after that remove it from the canvas when I click on one of the elements. How Can I do that? My example of code play sprite so fast, that I don't see animation. If I use "Thread.sleep()" it's total froze my game. Can anyone give me example, how i can solve this problem?! Main activity code onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);


            ...

    // explosion
    if (playExplosion) {

        for (int z = 1; z <= 10; z++) { // 10 images

            Rect src = null;
            Rect dst = null;

            if (spriteInt == 0) {
                // src = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
                src = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 1) {
                src = new Rect(80, 0, 120, 40);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 2) {
                src = new Rect(0, 40, 40, 80);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 3) {
                src = new Rect(40, 40, 80, 80);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 4) {
                src = new Rect(0, 80, 40, 120);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 5) {
                src = new Rect(40, 80, 80, 120);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 6) {
                src = new Rect(80, 40, 120, 80);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 7) {
                src = new Rect(80, 80, 120, 120);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 8) {
                src = new Rect(120, 0, 160, 40);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt++;
            } else if (spriteInt == 9) {
                src = new Rect(40, 0, 80, 40);
                dst = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40);
                spriteInt = 0;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmpExplosion, src, dst, null);
        }
        playExplosion = false;
    }
    // end

           ...


}
```

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or do you want to create a full game? You should try using an engine if you're making a game (like andengine) ... it will make your life a lot easier, and you get to focus on the game mechanics..

Comment: this is a simple game. i almost done it but i want add some animation

Answer (score 1):

you're almost there :-) the problem is that fundamentally you are linking the speed of the animation to the framerate. You will want to look into and understand interopolation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_%28computer_programming%29

You can use this to dictate how long you want the animation to take, then interpolate to figure out what the current frame should be, rather than simply incrementing the `SpriteInt` each frame

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still don't understand how to solve my problem. i tried to add one more thread for explosion, but it's still don't work like i want. i don't have good knowledge on android game development, but if you can write me some pice of code about how i can solve my problem it will be good :)

Comment: ok, it looks like you might need to go back and understand a few more first principles about game development. In this particular case, you need to understand the difference between a retained mode API (ie. the views), and an immediate mode API (ie. the game loop). Some good discussion here and in other places around the web: http://christiangenne.blogspot.com/2008/04/retained-or-immediate.html